# How to convert figma linear-gradient to react-native code?

Tags: react-native

I want to use this code :

```
background: linear-gradient(306.57deg, #8C25DE 29.82%, #F36BFF 115.65%);
```

in react native with `<LinearGradient />`

how can i handle this ?

Answer (score 1):

You could get close to the design by using the following configuration.

```
<LinearGradient
  useAngle={true}
  angle={306.57}
  locations={[.29, 1.15]}
  colors={['#F36BFF', '#8C25DE']}>
  <Text style={{padding: 20}}></Text>
</LinearGradient>
```

- `useAngle` and `angle` allows you to set the angle(in deg in Figma).
- `colors` define the two colors. You can use more colors if needed.
- `location` defines where each of the colors are in the gradient stops. This should be the same values that are defined in the percentages in the Figma CSS.

You can have a play around with the final output here: https://snack.expo.io/@nipuna777/gradients

Comment: thank you. However, i installed "react-native-web-linear-gradient" but it doesnt work  ? do you know problem ?  -v 0.63.2

Comment: I used `react-native-web-linear-gradient` in the snack because it's easier to preview in the 'web' tab. You should be using `react-native-linear-gradient` in a iOS/Android app. The code should still look the same.